# Why does this alternative method for determining the remainder when $19^{273}$ is divided by $12$ work?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

The question asked:

> Find the remainder when $19^{273}$ is divided by $12$.

My textbook shows an alternative method to complete this question, using modular arithmetic.

> If we let n be any number, such that:
>
> $ 19^{273}$ ≡ $ n^{273}$ (mod 12)
>
> $ 19^3 $ ≡ $n^3$ (mod 12)
>
> $ 6859$ ≡  $7$ (mod 12)
>
> Remainder is  $7$

Another example:

> $ 3^{2001} $ ≡ $ n^{2001} $ (mod 7)
>
> $($3^3 $)^{667}$ ≡ $($n^3 $)^{667}$ (mod 7)
>
> $ 3^3 $ ≡ 6(mod7) Therefore remainder  is 6

Why does this method work ? What is the purpose of n ?

The method I was familiar with was this:

> 19 ≡  7 (mod 12)
>
> $ 19^2$ ≡ 1(mod 12)
>
> $ 361^{136} $ ≡ $1^{136}$ ≡ 1(mod 12)
>
> Therefore 1 x 7  ≡ 7 (mod 12) Hence remainder is 7

Comment: I have no idea what the first method is saying.  I would have written $19^{273}\equiv 7^9\equiv 7\pmod {12}$ since $19\equiv 7\pmod {12}$ and $273\equiv 9 \pmod {11}$.

Comment: Clearly, they use 1) $19\equiv 7\bmod 12$ and 2) for every $n$ coprime with $12$,  we have $n^{273}\equiv n^{273\bmod\varphi{12}$ by Euler's theorem.

Comment: $19^3=6859$ rather than $6858$

Comment: $19\equiv 7 \mod 12$ and $19^2\equiv 1 \mod 12$ and $19^3\equiv 7 \mod 12$, so any odd power of $19$ is $\equiv 7 \mod 12$ and $273$ is odd

Comment: by Euler's thm., $19^{\phi(12)}=19^4\equiv1\bmod12$, so $19^{272}\equiv1\bmod12$, so $19^{273}\equiv19^{272}19\equiv19\equiv7\bmod12$

Comment: @lulu:  were you saying $\phi(12)=11$?!  $12$ is not prime!  $19^{285}\not\equiv7^{10}$ though $285\equiv10\bmod11$.  Or perhaps you meant $273\equiv9\bmod\color{red}4$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner  Ha!  Apparently I was.  Thanks for pointing out the blunder.  I blame it on lack of caffeine.

Comment: You should not accept answers that don't answer your question.  This may discourage  others from answering your question,

Comment: Do you have any more context that might hint what method the author was applying, e.g. are their immediately prior results or examples that might shed more light on their method?

Comment: Another example has been added to my original post of the method: 
$ 3^{2001} $ ≡ $ n^{2001} $ (mod 7)

$($3^3 $)^{667}$ ≡ $($n^3 $)^{667}$ (mod 7)

$ 3^3 $ ≡ 6(mod7) Therefore remainder  is 6

Comment: Unfortunately the new example still yields little insight. Which book are you using?